# How to point a compass arrow to a certain player?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

my cousin wants to play minecraft manhunt, but we play on ps4. I was wondering if  we could use a command block to make a compass arrow point at a certain player.

Comment: will you accept workarounds?

Comment: @Topcode wdym workarounds?

Comment: what i mean is things that arent exactly just like that. for example setting world spawn to the runners location makes a compass point at a player but can cause some problems

Comment: @topcode alright sure, how do you do that?

Comment: im not an expert at bedrock commands, so i dont know the exact syntax unfortunately.

Comment: @topcode ah okay thanks, but would happen to know of another person, or video by any chance if not you could even just tell me the command for pc and ill try to figure out how to make it work

Comment: We don't know if you have an experience on programming, but maybe try rebuilding the Java code in C++. The reason why I'm putting this in the comments is because this doesn't seem to be a workaround for you since you are on a PS4.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily possible with commands. Do:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ setworldspawn
```

This will make the compass point on them but unfortunately also makes players spawn there.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible with commands, but not for a long time.

You have to use the `/execute` command on the target player:

```
/execute <player> ~ ~ ~ spawnpoint <player> ~ ~ ~
```

> `<player>` 1 is the one who sets the spawn whilst `<player>` 2 is you

The reason why it won't be so used properly is because of a few reasons:

1. You will need the chunk where the command block to be loaded at all times. So if any of you go too far, the repeating command block won't work. It doesn't really help if you put multiple repeating command blocks around the world just so you can get him to set the world spawn.
2. It's a disadvantage to the runner if we want to reconsider Reason 1, because the hunter can easily respawn at the runner's current position which makes it easier to kill them.

Comment: Why would spawnpoint do this?

Comment: @Penguin Think about it a little. If you sleep in a bed, the compass arrow will now point there, meaning it is based off of the player spawn, not the world spawn.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 did that change in an update? That never used to be the case

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 [it hasnt changed, it still points to world spawn](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Compass)

Comment: Placing repeating command blocks isn't necessary via datapack

Comment: I've never fiddled with that in Bedrock though now that I think about it, it's most likely harder then it is in JE